# Free cloud providers for NET-CORE web-app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cloud

Up until now I was using Azure for my web-app(.NET-CORE & React & DB-relational).

I am looking for a free replacement for Azure. This is a small web-app so I need something simple and most important free. I am working on this project only for a learning purpose.

Will be happy t hear from your experience.

Thank you

Comment: You can use heroku to deploy your web app but you will need Docker to run your .net core app

Comment: Thanks. Any other options beside heroku ?

Comment: you can use Google cloud too